# When LockSupport.unpark() occur before LockSupport.park() , It would block in the park() method in the follow code, Why?

Tags: java, debugging, java-8, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

In javadoc , LockSupport.unpark() can occur before LockSupport.park() and guaranteed that next call to park is not to block.

> Makes available the permit for the given thread, if it was not already
> available. If the thread was blocked on park then it will unblock.
> Otherwise, its next call to park is guaranteed not to block. This
> operation is not guaranteed to have any effect at all if the given
> thread has not been started.

But in the follow code why it block at park() method , Sometimes but not always;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch c = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("t1 started");
            c.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("park...");
        LockSupport.park();
        System.out.println("resume...");
    });
    t1.start();
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
    System.out.println("unpark...");
    c.countDown();
}
```

I use CountDownLatch to make sure that unpark() occur before park(),
And I make sure that Thread t1 has been started , by call `t1.start()` before unpark();

Jdk Version 1.8;
The follow is result on my machine, block on the park() method, The guarantee dont work.

```
t1 started
unpark...
park...
```

[result pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KGVi.png)

Why? Did i do something stupid? Thankyou.

Comment: I think `CountDownLatch:await` consumes your unpark permits.

Comment: @akarnokd Many thanks, I checked the source code in `CountDownLatch:await `, that is **TRUE** ;  If `CountDownLatch:await` should be blocked, it will eventually call `LockSupport.park(this)` , This will definitely consume unpark permits；Thankyou again.